# How to use SpannableString in forLoop?

Tags: java, android, string, android-studio, spannablestring

I need to set the color of a part in a String where this String is augmented in every Loop (used in a forLoop).

So I tried the following code in a forLoop (after initializing `searchResults = "Hi";` outside the loop):

```
searchResults = searchResults + "x" + "y";
Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(searchResults);
spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), searchResults.length()-("x" + "y").length(), searchResults.length()-("y").length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
result.setText(spannable, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

But, only the last loop works.

As an example, suppose having the data set:

X: xxx, Y:yyy, Z:zzz

I am going to get:

x1, y1, z1

x2, y2, z2

x3, y3, z3

> I need all the x1, x2, x3 to be set in Green, but just x3 is returned
>   in Green and the others remain as they were.

what could be the solution?

Comment: question is not clear add sample image

Comment: what exactly do you want?

Comment: @NaveenKommuri
Edited: example added.

Comment: @RajatMehra Edited: example added.

Comment: @NaveenKommuri please use the text in the blockQuote as a description. I have problem  with uploading images in this site . . .